# VueJS doesn't render on MacOS (Safari and Chrome)

Tags: javascript, macos, vue.js, ipad, vuetify.js

I have a weird problem. My `VueJS` app (from CDN) uses `Vuetify`.

It works on Ubuntu and Windows, but my client sees the raw VueJS code on his Safari and also on Chrome on the iPad. Do you know where is the problem?

The simplified code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.20.0/axios.js"
            integrity="sha512-nqIFZC8560+CqHgXKez61MI0f9XSTKLkm0zFVm/99Wt0jSTZ7yeeYwbzyl0SGn/s8Mulbdw+ScCG41hmO2+FKw=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <v-app>
        <v-main>
            <v-container fluid>
             ....

            </v-container>
        </v-main>
    </v-app>

</div>
<script>
    class RepairsCalculator {
        ...
    }

    axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
    axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN"
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        data: {
            ...........
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your CDN or server may be misconfigured. It might be worth checking out the HTTP "Content-Type" headers to make sure it is sending out the right MIME type. You could examine this in chrome dev tools, by clicking on the network tab.

Chrome on iOS actually is based on WebKit, so it is running the same engine as Safari and their similar behavior should not be surprising.